# replace elements in a list with another list items content

Tags: jquery, list

I want to replace the first list item contents `sid` from second list items contents, ie `sid1=newsid1` using jQuery loop.

List one have `sid` which is inside the `div` which I want to replace from other list items content.

```
<ul class='list1'>
    <li>
        <div>name</div>
        <div>sid1</div>
        <div>role</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>name2</div>
        <div>sid2</div>
        <div>role2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>name3</div>
        <div>sid3</div>
        <div>role3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>name4</div>
        <div>sid4</div>
        <div>role4</div>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class='list2'>
    <li>new sid1</li>
    <li>new sid2</li>
    <li>new sid3</li>
    <li>new sid4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.list2 li').each(function(index){
    $('.list1 li:nth-child('+(index+1)+') div:nth-child(2)').text($(this).text());
});
```

Read `nth-child selector` on http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bqvVT/3/

Comment: its only replacing the first list. it should replace all others also like sid2=new sid2,sid3=new sid3,sid4=new sid4 and so on

Comment: @santanukumar Now check my answer once.

Comment: can we loop it using list1 as if there can be less no of or more no of items will be there in list1 or list2.

Comment: @santanukumar Yes, we can do it by testing `length` of `ul` and `loop` according to which one is `less` like `if($('.list1 li').length > $('.list2 li').length) { $('.list1 li').each(function(){}); } else {$('.list2 li').each(function(){});}` But in both the cases you have to `write different code`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.list1 > li > div:eq(1)').text($('.list2 > li:first').text());
```

here,

`$('.list1 > li > div:eq(1)')` **=> selects the  2nd `<div>` of `<li>`**.
`text()` => **get text of that selector.**
`$('.list2 > li:first').text()` => **get text of first `<li>` from `<ul>` with class list2.**
`.text($('.list2 > li:first').text());` =>**replaces text of 2nd `<div>` with the first.**
 `<li>`

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/36znB/)